# why is the constant FLAG_FULLSCREEN repeated in place of int mask in the following method?

Tags: java, android

```
setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: Because bitmasks are odd. `(-1, FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` should result in the same. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29

Comment: @zapl you mean to say bitmasks are or'ed right?

Comment: Odd. They often are or'd but they also lead to quite odd APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setFlags(int flags, int mask) {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getAttributes();
    attrs.flags = (attrs.flags&~mask) | (flags&mask);
    mForcedWindowFlags |= mask;
    dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(attrs);
}
```

*([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/Window.java#L851))*

the two `int` parameter are used in combination to specify which bits of the window flags field to set.

The first one is the source to copy from, e.g.

```
0000 0010 0000 0000
```

But that by itself is not enough because the program can not know which of these bits should be copied and which in the target field you want to keep. Maybe you even want to set one that is `0`.

So the second parameter (the `mask`) specifies which bits in the first parameter you mean. E.g.

```
0000 0011 0000 0000
```

would mean that you want to copy the 7th and 8th bit

```
0000 0010 0000 0000
0000 0011 0000 0000
------------------- 
.... ..10 .... ....   << sets those to bits two 10 while the rest remains untouched
```

The effect of using the flag twice is

```
0000 0010 0000 0000
0000 0010 0000 0000
------------------- 
.... ..1. .... ....
```

just one way to specify that you really mean that one bit flag. You could as well use all 1s in the `flags` field.

---

Assume initially the value of `attrs.flags` (the currently active window flags) are

```
0000 0000 0101 0101
       ^    ^   ^ ^- FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON is enabled
       |    |   |
       |    |   |--- another enabled feature
       |    |
       |    -------- a flag that isn't set.  
    assume this is FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

now you want to set just that 1 missing bit but `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` is a full 32bit `int`. If you would simply overwrite everything you would lose all the other nice bits that were set.

```
setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

means: "From those 32 bits in parameter 1 take the bits I've enabled in parameter 2 and replace the content of `attrs.flags` with them."

```
    0000 0000 0101 0101
  + .... ..1. .... .... (param1 combined with param2, dots are "masked out")
  = 0000 0010 0101 0101
```

And now the fullscreen flag is also set.